# what is the distance between top plate and resilient channel? what is the distance between resilient channels?

Tags: drywall, sound-proofing

I am learning how to soundproof my bedroom.

This guy is [demonstrating](https://youtu.be/xnarltDAUZQ?t=48)  "HOW TO INSTALL DRYWALL ON A CEILING WITH RESILIENT CHANNEL"

Consider the following image (img_1), screenshot from that tutorial at time point.

[image]

The red line segment denotes the space between the studs is 14 1/2 inches.

The red circle is pointing out the top plate of a stud wall.

The blue circle is pointing out the one resilient channel.

what is the distance between top plate and resilient channel?

what is the distance between resilient channels?

Comment: Hello again. You seem to be posting a large burst of not-all-that-appropriate questions. You should definitely [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking details about a random procedure which we couldn't know.

Comment: This sounds like a school project and the OP just wants us to answer all the questions.

Comment: @DanielGriscom I concur: 20+ ?'s in 2 days, most about basic knowledge that could've been answered by either; using google, watching the entire video, or reading the product literature/instructions. These questions are getting spammy and it looks like the community agrees. Most of his older questions have been down-voted. i.e. this question is a basic misunderstanding that the contractor started from the other side of the room, with another piece hidden by his hand. The space isn't even significant, it's just where the last piece fell. These are not good diy questions; en masse or apiece.

Comment: @JACK Can't "at" two people in one comment, but yes, I agree... something is afoot; it's an assignment/project, or beyond the scope of his abilities/reach. But either way, not the right questions to be asking if diy is the plan.

Comment: @tahwos Taking OP as an example, would you please show me how to use google get my answer? I don't want to be spammy either. Besides, it also took my time to screenshot and add annotation.

Comment: @zghqh, I tried to post and answer showing how to google the answers, but people downvoted it to deletion...

Comment: @JPhi1618 All of your answers are still present and I'm not seeing where anything of yours has been down-voted, which wouldn't cause deletion on its own in any case.

Comment: @zghqh The very same YouTuber that posted the video you linked to, has an entire series on this project, including installing the channel. None of your questions show that you have put any substantial effort into at the very least, asking something worthy of a well formed, valuable answer. Rather it looks like you just get to the next concept that you are unfamiliar with, and just post another question to DIY. Many of us have saved tags, that we get emails about, when new questions are asked with those tags - so when you post random, simple, common-knowledge questions, we all get notified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your [previous question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/183756/43874) on stud/channel spacing answers this question already.  The channels can be seen lining up with the studs in the above photo (to the left), and walls are normally framed with 16" on center studs.  The channels are 16" on center.

The distance you have marked in blue is not relevant.  The worker started installing the channels on the other side (to the left) and the small space you have marked is the space left over  (not all walls are multiples of 16" long).

Also, when hanging drywall or other paneling, the channels or studs that it attaches to will be spaced at even divisions of the panels length.  Drywall is 8' long and 4' wide, so that gives obvious possibilities of 16" and 24" spacing.

Answer (score 0):

User specifically asked for this answer in the comments, so I'm copy/pasting it here.  Originally written for [this question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/183756/43874).

---

When you have a question like this, it is best to do some minimal research to see if you can come up with a solution on your own.  Lets see what Google says about "24 on center"...

[image: google 24 on center]

The first page of results seem to imply that it has something to do with "framing" a house, and we get some suggested questions about "measuring" for 24 on center, and "studs" being on center and even "How to measure on center".

Expanding any one of those suggested questions or adding one of the additional search terms of "studs" or "measure" to your query will lead to 100s of sites that answer this very basic, fundamental question.

Community driven sites are about asking others to give up some of their time to help you with a genuine problem.  When you ask questions without taking any time to research it yourself, that can be seen as selfish and wasteful.

Here are some discussions that go into more detail:

[Not enough research == Not a real question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/180748/327010)

[Should a clear lack of research be grounds for closing a question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/102811/327010)

[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/101039) *StackOverflow is admittedly more strict on this, but they have 1000s of questions a day, so they have to be tighter on the rules...*